# openpyxl and pandas combined

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm completely new to Python and Pandas, After trial and error, I've Got the Code below in part 1 to do what I want. (I'd appreciate any advice if there is a better way to write this.)

This brings me to part 2 - Again when I run it it does what I want it to.

The problem is trying to run it as one command. - Any advice would be appreciated.

#Part 1

```
import pandas as pd  

import numpy as np  

import openpyxl  


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:-FIle.xlsx',
                 usecols=['Country', 'WFF Rank', 'Trainer', 'RDB Rating', 
'ImprovingHorse', 'Winner', 'Venue', 'Back Odd', 'Jockey', 'Horse', 'Date', 'Class 
Change'])  


df['True Odds'] = df['Back Odd'] -1  


df.loc[df['Back Odd'] == 0, 'True Odds'] = 0  



df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)  

df.loc[df['Winner'] == 'L', 'Winner'] = -1  
df.loc[df['Winner'] == 'P', 'Winner'] = -1  
df.loc[df['Winner'] ==  0, 'Winner'] = 0  

df.loc[df['Back Odd'] ==  0, 'Winner'] = 0  
df.loc[df['Winner'] ==  0, 'True Odds'] = 0  

df['ProfitLoss'] =np.where((df['Winner'] == -1), df['Winner'], df['True Odds'])  



df = df[(df['Country'] == 'United Kingdom') &  
         (df['WFF Rank'] == 1) &  
         (df['Improving Horse'] == 'Y') &  
         (df['Class Change'] >= 0) &  
         (df['RDB Rating'] >= 275)]  


df.to_excel("C:NewFilexlsx")  

print(df.to_string())
```

#**PART 2**

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:NewFile.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

cell = ws['O1']
cell.value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,O2:O555555)"
cell.data_type = 'f'

wb.save('C:Finished_Filexlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with an `openpyxl` *engine* :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("input_file.xlsx",
                    usecols=["Country", "WFF Rank", "Trainer", "RDB Rating", 
                             "Improving Horse", "Winner", "Venue", "Back Odd",
                             "Jockey", "Horse", "Date", "Class Change"])  

df["Winner"] = df["Winner"].replace(["L", "P"], -1)
df["True Odds"] = np.where(df["Back Odd"].ne(0), df["Back Odd"].sub(1), 0)
df["ProfitLoss"] = np.where(df["Winner"].eq(-1), df["Winner"], df["True Odds"])

df = df.loc[(df["Country"] == "United Kingdom") & (df["WFF Rank"] == 1) & 
            (df["Improving Horse"] == "Y") & (df["Class Change"] >= 0) & 
            (df["RDB Rating"] >= 275)]

with pd.ExcelWriter("output_file.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
    worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
    worksheet["O1"] = f"=SUM(O2:O{len(df)+1})"
```